# Can I use AWS Lambda for my requirements?

Tags: amazon-web-services, server

I recently visited "AWS Free Tier". Under that in "serverless" option is "AWS Lambda". I am trying to develop an application. I want to know what will be the best resource to use.

﻿USAGE: I need to connect to server through mobile app using HTTP POST. 1st it will register the bus number. Then it will add the corresponding bus stops and the fare between each bus stop. The app will next time send bus number and get all bus stops. Then it will select 2 bus stops and send to server. It will pay the required fare. Server will generate the bus ticket and store in database. It will send 1 copy  to the mobile.

I need an web server for development and testing purpose. I had started with JSP. But due to some reasons I was not able to access the JSP page through android app. However I was able to access the JSP through browser. In android app, I can access other websites. I think the url was the problem. So, I decided to use AWS server. Please let me know where I can use JSP. If you have any other server and database, please let me know. Currently I will be using it for development and testing purpose. So, 1-5 users may use it. But later I will run it as a business. Then more users will be using it. (So, please let me know about the payments for business use also, if you have idea about that) I will need database also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a service which recieves an HTTP request and accesses a database as part of the logic it performs to generate a response and host that service with AWS Lambda.

You would need a database in addition to AWS Lambda (there are many database services available from AWS and other providers).

You **can't** just drop your JSP files onto Lambda. It does not support JSP (although it does support programs written in Java).

Comment: I worked on jsp for 1 day, It is not fully built, that should not be a problem then, I can use java or python, is c or c++ option available? I am basically ac++ developer. Thanks

Comment: You can find some [details about lambda runtimes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtimes.html) here - Java and Python are supported natively. For C/C++ you'd need to either build your own runtime or use the new option to package lambda functions as docker containers.